# Ionic 3 Facebook login disabled (Facebook SDK deprecated)

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hi Guys i tried to login using ionic 3 facebook native , i am facing login issue for using old webview sdk for facebook , i tried many solutions can't resolve can any one help me to resolve this,

```
error_code=PLATFORM__LOGIN_DISABLED_FROM_WEBVIEW_OLD_SDK_VERSION
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, Facebook disabled login with embedded browser. Now you have to install Facebook application on your mobile to login.

Comment: Thanks its working after i download facebook app